# How can I set halftone (sethalftone) to each separation color with device tiffsep1 and other separation ones?

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript, postscript

The code works but the commented code will create an error. The error are not solved by changing `-sDEVICE` to `tiffgray`, for example.

```
String[] ARGS = new String[] {
                "",
                "-sDEVICE=tiffsep1",
                "-r1200",
                "-o out.tiff",
                "SOSample.pdf",
                //"-c",
                //"<< /HalftoneType 1 /Frequency 300 /Angle 45 /SpotFunction {180 mul cos exch 180 mul cos add 2 div} >> sethalftone",
                //"-f"
            };
```

**How can I define `sethalftone` with ghostscript and how can I set it for each color of `tiffsep1`?** What am I doing wrong with one color and how to make it for separations?

I'm using:

```
        [DllImport("gsdll64.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_init_with_args")]
        public static extern int INSTANCEStart(IntPtr instance, int argc, string[] argv);
```

and so on.

I'm working with **Ghostscript 9.52**.

Something that could help (`\"`):

```
"-c",
"\"<</Orientation 1>> setpagedevice\"",
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the sethalftone PostScript operator in order to change the halftone. Obviously this will involve writing some PostScript.

Not only that, but you really need to set the default halftone, or set the halftone at the start of the page, because the current PDF interpreter in Ghostscript does an initgraphics at the start of every page of a PDF file.

For all of this you are going to need a copy of the PostScript Language Reference Manual, which you can get from somewhere on the Adobe web site. They keep moving stuff around so I'm not going to try and post a link, just google for the name of the manual. You want the third edition.

So you need to write a BeginPage procedure, which you will find covered in Chapter 6 under device control, pages 427 onwards.

The BeginPage procedure will need to set a halftone, and you will find halftones covered in Section 7.4, page 480 onwards. You will presumably want to use either a type 2 or type 4 halftone dictionary.

When you've assembled that, you then need to pass it to Ghostscript **before** you process the PDF file. The simplest method is to put the PostScript program in a file (called eg setup.ps) and then put that filename on the command line immediately before the PDF filename.

Eg:

gs -r1200 -sDEVICE=tiffsep1 -o out%d.tif setup.ps sample.pdf

Note that PDF files can contain a halftone specification themselves (this is deprecated in PDF 2.0) and Ghostscript will honour any halftone in a PDF file.

Finally; this is an unusual request and, given that you are writing code to link to the Ghostscript DLL, makes me think you may be using Ghostscript commercially. You should review the AGPL to ensure you are complying with the terms of the license. If you plan on distributing your application you will almost certainly need a commercial license.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was just reading section 7.4, but maybe I'm rushing things, I'm new with PS, any introduction material to share? I was planning to take a look at language.htm from GS doc, looks relevant. I  know about the license, my project is safe for AGPL. It looks to be a way to write PS directly for the options, it looks like GS has recognised it as a PS code when I tried the the code in my last code box (it gives me a different error), when I add the Quotation marks with backslash. Maybe I should open a second question for this doubt.

Comment: language.htm is more about Ghostscript's specific implementation of the PostScript language, so it includes the architectural limits, extensions, etc. For general PostScript language questions you are best off with the PRLM. There are two other books, the blue book and the green book, tutorial and language design documents. Again these are on the Adobe web site and googling for PostScript Blue/Green Book should find them.