# How can i write a line in a pdf with a gradient with ghostscript/postscript with tiffsep1 device?

Tags: c#, pdf, postscript

I'm tring to modify a pdf with ghostscript via a ps file for add a transversal line, but it don't work for this file.

**Input files**

- [B&W pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Bfpa46bKzG0JlV9Hpz32TQ6GdPKyQNb/view?usp=sharing)
- [Gradient pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12_qdGKFj-x2FUvw6UxrXVmZ88AYIF6JY/view?usp=sharing)

**I tried**:

```
gs -sDEVICE=tiffsep1 -sCompression=lzw -r300x300 -o out%d.tif post.ps input.pdf
```

**post.ps**:

```
%!
<<
    /BeginPage {
    newpath
        0 0 moveto
        1000 1000 lineto
    stroke
    } bind
    /Orientation 3
>> setpagedevice
```

- The black output for my **B&W pdf** do have the line, but the black output for the **Gradient pdf** don't have it.
- The line seems to be under the pdf!?
- The `/Orientation` for both outputs is correct.

**How can I get the expected output for my file with a gradient?**

.

I'm calling **gs** in c# the same way as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082203/how-can-i-set-halftone-sethalftone-to-each-separation-color-with-device-tiffse/63087141).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of your PDF files contains no transparency operations, so they are opaque. In the case of your B&W file the only marks made on the page are the black areas, in the case of your Gradient file, almost the entire page is marked by the gradient fill.

The BeginPage PostScript procedure is executed at the **beginning** of the page, before the page contents are processed.

So what happens is that a black line is drawn, then the black marks from the B&W file are drawn. Where the black line is not covered by the black areas of the page contents you can see the line (had you drawn the line in, say, red, you would see where the black areas cover the line).

Your gradient file covers the entire area where the initial black line was drawn, so you can't see any of it.

If you want the line drawn 'on top' of the page content, then you need to use an EndPage procedure, not a BeginPage.

Comment: Yeah, I have already tried the same ps with EndPage in place of BeginPage, but that way GS returns an error, any idea why? Is there anything else that I need to do to the code to work?

Comment: Well you didn't tell me the error, which would be kind of helpful.... I suspect the problem is that the PDF interpreter also calls setpagedevice to set the media size from the MediaBox in the PDF file. That's probably a bug in the PDF interpreter at a guess. Adding -dPDFDEBUG shows that the PDF interpreter starts running the PDF file before the error, which seems to me like good evidence that its a bug in the PDF interpreter. You should open a bug report.

Comment: The exactly code don't work changing BeginPage to EndPage, but EndPage must take 2 integers, consume them and return a boolean value, than it works adding "exch pop 2 ne" after stroke

Answer (score 1):

This case was reported as a bug in Ghostscript.
https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=702597
In fact, the supplied /EndPage procedure was invalid.
/BeginPage and /EndPage procedures are not interchangeable.
See PostScript Language Reference Manual, "6.2.6 Device Initialization and Page Setup" for details.